# What is better, use the mysql "select from table where..." or move the whole table to Arraylist and iterate through it?

Tags: java

I'm trying to find a specific record. So what's better to do? Use a mysql statement to find the record or grab the whole table, put in a arraylist and iterate through it until I find what I want?

Comment: Consider the case where the table has tens of millions of rows...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is always better to offload database work to database.

Some of the advantages I see are:

You will get only the data you want, which improves performance, result will be faster (Most of database servers comes with optimization to improve query execution paths).

Save the space. You don't need to keep unwanted data in runtime memory

Comment: Not to mention the possibility that there just might even be an index on the very column that one is trying to find.... :)

Comment: Ok, i'm new to programming and i'm just trying to understand the best practices. Thanks!

Comment: @PauloBarbosa: That is perfectly fine. Good luck.

Comment: @PauloBarbosa: Accepting an answer will motivate community in answering your questions. Click tick mark right beside appropriate answer to accept it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think making a `Database query` will be **faster and efficient** than **taking all the data into** `ArrayList` and then processing it...

MoreOver writing a logic will be hectic if that can be solved with one well prepared query to the database...

`ArrayList` is an `object` itself, and i think you will also need to store the datas in the DB as an Object of some `custom made class`... **That will take space**.....!!!

Sometime you may need **only a small piece of info**, consider just a value from a table... then i think using something like `ArrayList` is **not a smart move**....